# matlab: uigetfile with one or multiple files

Tags: matlab, file

I have a stupid problem. I want to know how many files were selected after:

```
[fileName, pathName, filterIndex] = uigetfile({'*.*';'*.xls';'*.txt';'*.csv'}, 'Select file(s)', 'MultiSelect', 'on');
```

when there was more than 1, i can do 
length(fileName);

and its ok. But when there was only one selected, this gives me actual length of fileName (amount of chars) :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably check with [`iscell(filename)`](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/iscell.html) first.

```
[fileName, pathName, filterIndex] = uigetfile({'*.*';'*.xls';'*.txt';'*.csv'}, 'Select file(s)', 'MultiSelect', 'on');

if isequal(fileName, 0)
    disp('User selected Cancel');
else
    if iscell(fileName)
        nbfiles = length(fileName);
    elseif ~isempty(fileName)
        nbfiles = 1;
    else
        nbfiles = 0;
    end
end
```

UPDATE: added check on cancellation from [`uigetfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html) as was suggested in a comment.

Comment: thank you @cooltea , in Matlab 2022b, we should check cancelation with `isequal(fileName,0)` condition. it is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

filename = cellstr(filename)

is another (easier) solution to always receive a cell of filenames indpendent if 1 or more files are choosen